# Child class attributes point to the same object reference from parent

Tags: python, oop

Basing on the code below, I had expected `student.hobbies` to be separate from `player.hobies`, but it seems they both point to the same reference object and performing an operation on one affects the other.

```
class Person:
    hobbies = []

class Student(Person):
    pass

class Player(Person):
    pass

student = Student()
player = Player()

student.hobbies.append("Reading")
player.hobbies.append("Playing")

print(student.hobbies) # prints >> ['Reading', 'Playing'] 
print(player.hobbies) # prints >> ['Reading', 'Playing']
```

Though they share the same base class, `student` and `player` are two separate instances of two separate classes. So I expected `student.hobbies` to return `['Reading']` and `player.hobbies` to return `['Playing']` after performing the append operation on each but that's clearly not the case. What am I not getting right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because in your example `hobbies` is a class variable, not an instance variable. Use `__init__` to declare it

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hobbies = []

print(student.hobbies)  # ['Reading']
print(player.hobbies)  # ['Playing']
```